# Migrating from php 5.4 to 5.5

Tags: php, apache

I have simple page written in php which works like single page application, i just use `include_once` when user want to go to other subpage.Sub pages are pure html but they are saved with extension `.php` My hosting owner said they are moving to php 5.5, so i have checked on wamp with php 5.5 if page works and it does. But on hosting it cause internal server error, even simple page with `php_info()` cause it, php versin is set by `.httaccess` file

```
 <Files *.php>
 ForceType application/x-httpd-php55
</Files>
```

Is this something wrong with provider apache configuration? If so what it might be? I'm using standard php.ini generated file.

Comment: Has your hosting provider *actually* migrated to PHP 5.5 yet? Realistically you shouldn't have to try and force the version in an .htaccess file, they should have it all configured at the top server level - httpd.conf

Comment: its temporary solution for those who didnt change php version yet, but they want to check if page works.

Comment: Try `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .phtml` instead? (without the `<Files> ... </Files>`)

Comment: it cause downloading page instead of interpreting

Comment: It's possible they've not actually upgraded PHP yet on the server then - `ForceType` just fudges the MIME type, it doesn't actually affect the PHP interpreter I don't think. AddHandler however would invoke the PHP 5.5 interpreter - and if it's not yet installed Apache won't know how to handle the file and you'll get the download prompt.

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code (or a blank page) basically means "please check server logs to read the actual error message". You need to do that.

Comment: I dont have access to apache error.log, but i will try to

Comment: it turns out that `/tmp` folder was missing thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that /tmp folder was missing thanks for help